# How do I get AngularJS to set my model property to null instead of undefined from <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have several  elements on my site with the options bound to complex objects that have integer IDs.  The dropdown's value is bound to the object's ID like so:

```
<select id="selThings" name="selThings" class="form-control" 
 ng-change="onOptionChange('thing.id')" ng-model="data.thing.id" convert-to-number>
    <option value={{null}}>
        Select a thing...
    </option>
    <option ng-repeat="thing in data.things" value="{{thing.id}}">
        {{thing.displayName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

My convert-to-number directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('convertToNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                return val !== undefined && val !== null && val !== '' ? parseInt(val, 10) : null;
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (val) {
                return val !== undefined && val !== null ? '' + val : null;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This works fine as long as a non-null option was selected.  The model value is correctly set to an integer instead of a string value (ie 5 instead of "5"); the problem is when the null option is slected. The convertToNumber directive correctly returns a value of null from `return val !== undefined && val !== null ? '' + val : null;`.  However, if I put a $watch on my controller for thing.id, when it hits, thing.id's new value is `undefined`.

I have tried using `ng-option` instead of `<option ng-repeat...>` but with no luck.  As a workaround, I'm using `ng-change="onOptionChange('thing.id')"` which parses out the property, and if it's undefined, changes it to null.  My boss and I agree that this is a messy ugly way to handle the situation, so I need to find a better way of setting the model property to `null`.

Comment: You can keep folks from selecting your placeholder text option by adding the attribute `disabled` to the option. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/christophersw1/qenzrkjg/1/).

Comment: Could you provide with a plunker?

Comment: @christophersw Unfortunately, the users need to be able to select the placeholder text, per the spec.

Comment: Ok, see if this is what you are looking for: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMlUpTUt90oOcr0iMmrt?p=preview). This defaults to null, and allows you to select the placeholder text (also sets to null). I'm guessing this might not fix your problem, but it might help get us on the same page about exactly what you need. @MarcusH, as requested, I've included a "with disabled" section there to show the basic HTML option for disabling selection of the placeholder option.

Comment: @christophersw Your plunkr is perfect for what I need.  I just can't seem to make it happy on our site.  It does give me somewhere to start though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define empty Object with empty values for all properties which is in object